# Converting IO [FilePath] to String or Bytestream

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm working on [this project](https://github.com/leonstafford/mini_haskell_webapp) to get feet wet with Haskell and struggling with finding simple examples.

In this instance, I would like to have a web request handler for Snap, which returns a list of files in a directory.

I believe I'm trying to get the return of [getDirectoryContents](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.0.0.0/docs/System-Directory.html#v%3AgetDirectoryContents) into a Bytestring which [Snap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.6.3/docs/Snap-Core.html) wants.

I am most confused about what to do with the return value I get at the line `filenames <- getDirectoryContents "data"` below:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Snap.Core
import Snap.Util.FileServe
import Snap.Http.Server
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents)

main :: IO ()
main = quickHttpServe site

site :: Snap ()
site =
    ifTop (writeBS "hello world") <|> 
    route [ ("foo", writeBS "bar")
          , ("echo/:echoparam", echoHandler)
          , ("view_root_json_files", listRootFilesHandler)
          ] <|> 
    dir "static" (serveDirectory ".")

echoHandler :: Snap ()
echoHandler = do
    param <- getParam "echoparam"
    maybe (writeBS "must specify echo/param in URL")
          writeBS param

listRootFilesHandler :: Snap ()
listRootFilesHandler = do
    -- read all filenames in /data folders
    filenames <- getDirectoryContents "data"
    writeText filenames
```

Comment: It might be as well to skip the Strings entirely and use the very high quality `posix-paths` library, which uses strict ByteString for file names and so on http://hackage.haskell.org/package/posix-paths-0.2.0.3/docs/System-Posix-Directory-Traversals.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to use `writeText`, you need to convert `[FilePath]` to `Text`. Luckily, `Text` is an instance of `Monoid`, and a list is a instance of `Foldable`, so we can simply use `foldMap pack filenames` to get a single text:

```
-- import Data.Foldable (foldMap)
-- import Data.Text (pack, Text)

toText :: [FilePath] -> Text
toText = foldMap pack
```

Note that you'll need to use `liftIO` to actually use a `IO a` in `Snap b`, since `Snap` is an instance of `MonadIO`:

```
listRootFilesHandler :: Snap ()
listRootFilesHandler = do
    filenames <- liftIO $ getDirectoryContents "data"
    writeText $ toText filenames
```

If you want to add a newline (or `<br/>`) after each `FilePath`, add `flip snoc '\n'`:

```
toText = foldMap (flip snoc '\n' . pack)
-- toText = foldMap (flip append (pack "<br/>") . pack)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough example and suggestions for additional things based on the context of the question. I did need to also import `import Control.Monad.IO.Class` to get the liftIO working.

Comment: * and was unable to satisfy dependencies for snoc, so left it as one big string for now

Comment: @LeonStafford: Yeah, I forgot the import for `liftIO`. You need to modify the `import Data.Text` in order to import `snoc`: `import Data.Text (Text, pack, snoc)`. Oh, and while we're at it and you're apparently new to Haskell, have a look at the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia). Don't fret if you don't understand everything the first time, but keep it in mind when you encounter "new" standard classes (`Traversable`, `Foldable`, `Monoid`, `Applicative`).

Answer (score 2):

You can't "convert" an `IO` action to a string. Of course not, it's a completely different thing, conceptually. What you can do is extract / "focus" a value in a monad, such as `IO`. That's what the `val <- action` syntax in a `do` block is used for, you have that quite correct.

The only problem with your current implementation is that you have an `IO`-monad action, but want to execute it in the `Snap` monad. Well, actually `Snap` *is* deep down the `IO` monad, [with a whole lot of extra stuff attached](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.6.3/docs/src/Snap-Internal-Types.html#Snap) via monad transformers. But you can always use `Snap` as if it were `IO`. That's true for a whole bunch of monads (all that are created by stacking transformers on `IO`), so there's [a dedicated class for "monads that can do IO"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#t:MonadIO).

```
listRootFilesHandler = do
    -- read all filenames in /data folders
    filenames <- liftIO $ getDirectoryContents "data"
    ...
```

The other, rather easier thing is flattening a `[FilePath]` list to a single string. I suppose you know how to do that.

Comment: re flattening filepath to a single string - I'm as unfamilar as with anything else in Haskell :P Assuming [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mime-string-0.2/docs/Codec-MIME-String-Flatten.html) one?